# IntegrityError: duplicate key value violates unique constraint

Tags: django

I created a model in a django app and populated the data into the table from pgadmin but now when I am trying to create a record from the app it throws this integrity error:

> duplicate key value violates unique constraint "packsapp_foo_pkey"
>
> DETAIL:  Key (id)=(4) already exists.

Here's the models.py

```
class foo(models.Model):
    a = models.CharField(max_length=500, default=0)
    b = models.EmailField(max_length=500, default=0)
    c = models.CharField(max_length=500, default=0)
    d = models.CharField(max_length=500, default=0)
```

Do I always have to insert data from the app itself ?

Views.py

```
class ProductFormView(CreateView):
    model = Product
    form_class = Productaddform

    template_name = 'packsapp/employee/employeeProductForm.html'

    def form_valid (self, form):
        product = form.save(commit=False)
        print("user ", self.request.user.id)
        product.product_owner = Employee.objects.filter(user = self.request.user.id)[0]
        product.save()
        messages.success(self.request, 'The product was created with success! ')
        return redirect('employee:products_table')
```

Comment: Seems you are passing the pk while inserting the new data. Please show your insert   code

Comment: please also share your migration file

Comment: @cwhisperer No I am not passing the pk, my formclass just consists of a,b,c,d

Comment: @UsmanMaqbool I deleted the migrations mistakenly, no longer have them

Comment: Then run makemigrations and migrate commands, then try

Comment: @UsmanMaqbool I did that, nothing changed! also I added my views.py

Comment: Looks like your database pk sequence is out of sync. This can happen if you force the values of auto primary keys. I don't remember exactly how the sequence is handled in postgres but it's documented anyway.

Answer (score 1):

Agree with bruno's comment where your primary key sequence is not in sync. To fix this, run the following in a PG console:

```sql
SELECT setval(pg_get_serial_sequence('packsapp_foo', 'id'), max("id")) FROM "packsapp_foo";
```

To enter values manually in the DB, make sure to call `nextval(<sequence>)` for `id` when inserting -- this will keep the pk sequence synchronized, e.g.:

```sql
INSERT INTO packsapp_foo
  (id, a, b, c, d)
VALUES
  (next_val(pg_get_serial_sequence('packsapp_foo', 'id')), ...);
```

The same applies for any other sequences you may have on your table columns. See [Postgres Docs](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/functions-sequence.html) for updating sequences